# How to extend the I18n.translate method in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, internationalization

right now when if I have in my app some code like

```
<%= t :test %>
```

and there is no translation available for :test I get something like this in my view:

```
<span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.test">Test</span>
```

What I would like to add is to include a similar span even for existing translations, so if the translation exists I would like to get something like:

```
<span class="translation_existing" title="translation existing: en.test">Translated string</span>
```

note the different class name in the span. And the string should be really translated.

How can I achieve this result by overriding the translate method?

Thank you in advance

Gnagno

Answer (score 2):

"t" is a view helper :
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-t

it is easy to view its source code and to create your own, you can also override the helper by redefining it in your ApplicationHelper.

But IMHO, you should not redefine it, but create your own one with a different name. There are so many cases where you'll want to use the "t" helper in parts of your views that would screw up if you insert additional HTML markup (ie. : I use the "t" helper in the  section of my pages to translate the title, meta tags, etc)...

Answer (score 1):

I created a helper that overwrites 't' method, which is just shortcut for 'translate':

```
def t(*a)           # I don't care what params go in
  key = a.first     # just want to override behaviour based on the key

  #if my overrides contain the key
  if value = @i18n_overrides["#{I18n.locale}.#{key}"] 
    return value # return the overrided value
  end

  translate(*a) # otherwise letting i18n do its thing
end
```

More clean approaches would be these, but they didn't work for me:

Tried using alias but realised that `t` or `translate` dont' exist in that scope at the point of execution of class body.

Tried calling `ActionView::Helpers::TranslationHelper.translate` instead of just `translate` but that didn't work either.